# Weborf terminated with exit code 3

Tags: networking, sharing

I am still new to using Ubuntu. i am running Ubuntu desktop 20.04.6. i am trying to share with write access to my windows 11 PC on my local network. i installed qweborf. the idea was i could not "see" my Ubuntu PC on my windows PC. and i "see" my windows network icon on my Ubuntu PC, but i can not access it when i click on it. so i am trying to configure my Ubuntu PC to be "seen" on my win 11 computer. directory in qweborf im trying to share is: /home/edwin/Public with the write access checked.

Comment: When i try to do the local network share on properties it gives me this: 'net usershare' returned error 255

Comment: I searched askubuntu for that error and did not find a solution